# bash wildcard expansion stops after some time

Tags: bash

I am using bash 4.3 [on debian jessie 8.5, kernel 3.16.7-ckt25-2].

I am opening a console window (with xfce4) or a ssh session and enter shell commands.
Sometimes later, shellexpansion stops working. Example:

```
ls /usr/lib/u*
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/u*: No such file or directory
```

Opening a new session (ssh in this case) and doing the same:

`ls /usr/lib/u*
/usr/lib/udisks2:
total 397
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1328 Sep 30  2014 udisks2-inhibit*
.....`

I compared the `BASHOPTS` (in the output of `set`) in both sessions show any differences. This happen very often, so I have really to get rid of it.
But. after digging deeper, I found an alias like this, which caused it:

```
alias di='set -f; /ops/tools/di'
```

So, my final question is: How do I come to the same result, without
making the "-f" permanent (I even don't find, where this is saved). `SHOPT`'s are not the place.

Any help, pointers or further information are really welcome!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint about superuser/unix, looks right!
The 'di' is a shell script, which wraps the execution of a tool,which I want to pass wildcard-like characters without the ugly escaping. It passes all commandline arguments without any modification/expansion to an application. So, this wrapper itself 'is too late' to disable expansion with 'set -f', the caller of the wrapper has to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `di` does, but I'd try:

`alias di='set -f; /ops/tools/di; set +f'`

in this case, `set +f` actually *unsets* the `f [Disable file name generation (globbing).]` flag.